# Complete turn x angle values are mapped to half turn using asin function, how to mirror them back?

Tags: python, numpy, angle

I have angles that form a complete turn in an array `x`, from -90 to 270 e.g. (it may be defined otherwise, like from 0 to 360 or -180 to 180) with step 1 or whatever.

`asin` function is valid *only* between -90 and +90.

Thus, angles < -90 or > 90 would be "mapped" between these values.

E.g. `y` = some_asin_func(over_sin(`x`)) will end up in an `y` value that is always between -90 and +90. So `y` is stuck between -90 and +90.

I do need to retrieve to which x-input is `y` related, because it's ambiguous yet: for example, the function over (`x`) will give the same `y` values for `x = 120` and `x = 60`, or `x = -47` and `x = 223`. Which is not what I want.
Put an other way; I need `y` making a complete turn as `x` does, ranging from where `x` starts up to where `x` ends.

An image will be better:

[image: original_curves1]

Here, `x` ranges between -90 (left) to 270 (right of the graph).
The valid part of the curve is between `x=-90` and `x=+90` (left half of the graph).
All other values are like mirrored about y=90 or `y=-90`.
For `x=180` for example, I got `y=0` and it should be `y=180`.
For `x=270`, I have `y=-90` but it should be `y=270`, thus +360.

Here's a code sample:

```
A   = 50 # you can make this value vary to have different curves like in the images, when A=0 -> shape is triangle-like, when A=90-> shape is square-like.
x   = np.linspace(-90,270,int(1e3))
u   = np.sin(math.pi*A/180)*np.cos(math.pi*x/180)
v   = 180*(np.arcsin(u))/math.pi
y   = 180*np.arcsin(np.sin(math.pi*x/180)/np.cos(math.pi*v/180))/math.pi
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.grid(True)
```

Once again, first left half of the graph is completely correct. 
The right half is also correct in its behavior, but in final, here, it must be mirrored about an horizontal axis at position `y=+90` when `x>90`, like this:

[image: wanted_curves1]

That is, it's like the function is mirrored about **y=-90** and **y=+90** for `y` where `x` is out of the range [-90,+90] and only where where `x` is out of the range [-90,+90].

I want to *un-mirror* it outside the valid [-90,+90] range:
 about `y=-90` where `y` is lower than -90
 about `y=+90` where `y` is greater than +90

And of course, modulo each complete turn.

Here an other example where `x` ranges from -180 to 180 and the desired behavior:

Yet:

[image: original_curves2]

Wanted:

[image: wanted_curves2]

I have first tested some simple thing up now:

```
A = 50
x = np.linspace(-180,180,int(1e3))
u = np.sin(math.pi*A/180)*np.cos(math.pi*x/180)
v = 180*(np.arcsin(u))/math.pi 
y = 180*np.arcsin(np.sin(math.pi*x/180)/np.cos(math.pi*v/180))/math.pi
for i,j in np.ndenumerate(x):
    xval = (j-180)%180-180
    if (xval < -90):
        y[i] = y[i]-val
    elif (xval > 90):
        y[i] = y[i]+val

plt.plot(x,y);
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

which doesn't work *at all* but I think the background idea is there...
I guess it may be some kind of *modulo trick* but can't figure it out.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand what you are trying to do. Do you want x-y pairs on a unit circle as a function of the angle in polar coordinates?

Comment: Backgroud could be seen like I'd like to retrieve a star azimut (measured on an horizontal plane) based on its angle on the equatorial plane it's moving on, relative to the north. So I need to retrieve full 0-360 y-values based on function on full other 0-360 x-values.

Comment: Did I understand the core of the question correctly: you want to define a curve like in the second graph?

Comment: Yes, indeed, like both second graphs, independently of the range from the input values. Result should show the complete 360 turn variation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Thomas Kühn, it seems fine except I wanted to restrict the function in a single same turn in respect to y-values. Anyway, it's only aesthetics.

Here's what I found by my side. It's maybe not perfect but it works:

```
A = 50
u = np.sin(math.pi*A/180)*np.cos(math.pi*x/180)
v = 180*(np.arcsin(u))/math.pi
y = 180*np.arcsin(np.sin(math.pi*x/180)/np.cos(math.pi*v/180))/math.pi
for i,j in np.ndenumerate(x):
    val = (j-180)%360-180
    if (val < -90):
        y[i] = -180-y[i]
    elif (val > 90):
        y[i] = 180-y[i]
```

Here are some expected results:

[image: Results1]

Range from -180 to +180

[image: Results1]

Range from 0 to +360

[image: Results3]

Range from -720 to +720

[image: Results4]

Range from -360 to +360 with some different `A` values.

Funny thing is that it reminds me some electronics diagrams as well.
Periodic phenomenons are everywhere!

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution that fixes the periodicity of the `cos` function 'brute force' by calculating an `offset` and a `sign` correction based on the `x` value. I'm sure there is something better out there, but I would almost need a drawing with the angles and distances involved.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(4,4))

x = np.linspace(-540,540,1000)
sign = np.sign(np.cos(np.pi*x/180))
offset = ((x-90)//180)*180

for A in range(1,91,9):

    u   = np.sin(np.pi*A/180)*np.cos(np.pi*x/180)
    v   = 180*(np.arcsin(u))/np.pi
    y   = 180*np.arcsin(np.sin(np.pi*x/180)/np.cos(np.pi*v/180))/np.pi
    y   = sign*y + offset

    ax.plot(x,y)

ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

The result for the interval `[-540, 540]` looks like this:

[image: result of the given code]

Note that you can get `pi` also from `numpy`, so you don't need to import `math` -- I altered the code accordingly.

**EDIT**:
Apparently I first slightly misunderstood the OP's desired output. If the calculation of `offset` is just slightly changed, the result is as requested:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(4,4))

x = np.linspace(-720,720,1000)
sign = np.sign(np.cos(np.pi*x/180))
offset = ((x-90)//180 +1 )*180 - ((x-180)//360+1)*360

for A in range(1,91,9):

    u   = np.sin(np.pi*A/180)*np.cos(np.pi*x/180)
    v   = 180*(np.arcsin(u))/np.pi
    y   = 180*np.arcsin(np.sin(np.pi*x/180)/np.cos(np.pi*v/180))/np.pi
    y   = sign*y + offset

    ax.plot(x,y)

ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

The result now looks like this:

[image: updated figure]